# How to stop ggplotly() changing the position of the side labels of a faceting plot in an unexpected way?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggplotly

On the following faceting plot, the side label is displayed on the left using `switch = "y"` argument:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(drv), switch = "y")
```

And here is the plot:

[image]

However, when I convert it into an interactive plot using `plotly::ggplotly(p)`, the side label switched back to its default position on the right like this:

[image]

How can I keep the side label on the left? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's an issue reported here https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1086

Comment: Thank you. The ticket was opened in 2017 and is closed now. Do you know if the issue is fixed? Or is there any alternative way?

Comment: I have no idea.